# how to select query with where clause data in row separated by comma

Tags: mysql

honestly i don't know the right title for my problem and i am still newbie about query things. So I have table name EVENT like this

```
id_event      name_event          category
----------------------------------------------
   1            Market        Food,Fashion,Art
   2            Concert             Music
   3            FoodTruck       Food,Bevarage
```

My problem is i want to select category where category = "Food,Fashion" . So All category which have "Food" and "Fashion" will be out and the result be like this

```
 id_event      name_event          category
----------------------------------------------
   1            Market        Food,Fashion,Art
   3            FoodTruck       Food,Bevarage
```

Maybe someone can help me, Thank You Guys and Have a nice day!! Cheerss!!

Comment: Sorry to say you have a wrong database design. Comma separated data in a field is always a sign of that. Please sort that out before going any further because further down the line it will be more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can achieve what you want:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM event
WHERE category REGEXP CONCAT('(^|,)(', REPLACE("Food,Fashion", ',', '|'), ')(,|$)');
```

---

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a53959/1/0)

**Note:**
If you want to see the generated regular expression in the above query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('(^|,)(', REPLACE("Food,Fashion", ',', '|'), ')(,|$)') AS 'REGEXP';
```

**Result:**
`(^|,)(Food|Fashion)(,|$)`

***Explanation:*** Records will be selected having `Food/fashion` in `category` name only if anyone of the following condition is met:

- `food/fashion` has a **comma** before it or
- `category` starts with `food/fashion` or
- `category` ends with `food/fashion` or
- `food/fashion` has a **comma** after it.

**Suggestion:**

[**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Thank You @1000111 for your answer and once again thank you for your link

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your explanation!!

Comment: @Rei Except for the last line, this is a terrible solution

Comment: @Strawberry hey thank you for your response, yes i know, because i am using separated comma right?